# Simple, efficient FIFO queue with Elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there a built-in datatype that I can use for a FIFO queue in Elixir?

I have looked at list, but it seems like it is not efficient to get the list tail?  Maybe I am wrong about this?

My queue needs to hold a 100,000 or more elements.
My need is that I am generating 44100 tuples a second of the form {t, y} for audio.  I am trying to implement a delay, so I need to queue up a couple of seconds (maybe 10 at max?) of audio before sending it down the processing pipeline.

Comment: Have you checked Erlang queue - http://erlang.org/doc/man/queue.html ?

Comment: I just found out about this, it looks like exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: arathunku, the erlang queue worked perfectly, if you make this an answer I'll accept

Comment: Josh, that's great it solved the problem! I've added the answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm not sure about the performance on 100,000 or more elements but it looks like you're looking for [Queue](http://erlang.org/doc/man/queue.html). It's a FIFO Queue provided by the Erlang/OTP.

Example:

```
iex(39)> queue = :queue.new                            
{[], []}
iex(40)> queue = :queue.in(1, queue)                   
{[1], []}
iex(41)> queue = :queue.in(2, queue)                   
{[2], [1]}
iex(42)> queue = :queue.in(3, queue)
{[3, 2], [1]}
iex(43)> :queue.out(queue)                             
{{:value, 1}, {[3], [2]}}
iex(44)> {{:value, head}, queue} = :queue.out(queue)
{{:value, 1}, {[3], [2]}}
iex(45)> head
1
iex(46)> {{:value, head}, queue} = :queue.out(queue)
{{:value, 2}, {[], [3]}}
iex(47)> head
2
iex(48)> {{:value, head}, queue} = :queue.out(queue)
{{:value, 3}, {[], []}}
iex(49)> head
3
iex(51)> :queue.out(queue)        
{:empty, {[], []}}
```

Comment: What about something replicated across nodes?

Comment: Since Erlang code is often used in soft-realtime applications, beware of *amortized* perf characteristics of standard `queue`. For example, after 100,000 `in` calls, the first `out` call will be an O(N) operation. But then remaining 99,999 `out` calls will be O(1).

Comment: Do you have a simple example you can add to the answer?

Comment: @arcseldon added

Comment: There are also a number of Elixir wrappers around Erlang's `queue`. I like [`Qex`](https://github.com/princemaple/elixir-queue) because it adds protocol implementations for `Enumerable`, among others.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something with a bit more features than erlang's `:queue`, I built this Elixir queuing library a while ago: https://github.com/fredwu/opq

It offers functionalities such as worker pool and rate limit, etc. And, it is built on top of `:queue`. :)

A quick example:

```
{:ok, opq} = OPQ.init()

OPQ.enqueue(opq, fn -> IO.inspect("hello") end)
OPQ.enqueue(opq, fn -> IO.inspect("world") end)
```